# HTTPS (secure) POST issue in C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, https

I am creating a WinForms application in C# and it is using the POST method to send a buffer to an HTTPS website. When I send the data under HTTPS, the uploaded data is duplicated.  For example, if my send in my buffer **Hi** , it sends **HiHi** to the server.

It works as expected though under a normal HTTP connection. Only under secure connection does this issue occur.

I put a break point on the stream-write just before sending the data and the buffer contains the correct data. Why does it send the double information under HTTPS?

headers:

```
   POST /login/ HTTP/1.0
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Host: abc.test.com
   Content-Length: 12

   username=bobusername=bob
```

-

This is the code I am currently using:

```
string post_data = "username=bob";

string uri = "https://abc.test.com/login/";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(uri); 
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

MessageBox.Show(postBytes.Length.ToString());
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string tmp = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Comment: anybody any hints? i have asked so many people about this issue.. strange, no helpful hints.. havent anybody tried c# HTTPS POST before?